# Auto Posting to Multiple Facebook Pages using Graph API - Auth Issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am pulling my hair out trying to understand what Facebook wants me to do to post to a FaceBook Page as a System User that has Admin and Page Privileges to and Owned by our business (We have Facebook Business Manager).

In a nut shell all I want to do is make this call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/${MyPageID}/feed
```

What I don't get is the **access_token** part. 
I can generate access tokes for Apps, for Pages but all result in 403 returned from FaceBook. I have gone as far and checking every box available on the generate access token popup on the graph api and still I get 403 "Forbidden" so I am detailing the little I understand of the insanity that is FaceBook Auth in the hope that someone can explain where I am going wrong.

1) To Post as a System User to a Page I have to Create a FB App (I Would prefer just to post direct to the pages and skip the App part, My System User has Admin Access on All pages)

2) To Access the App I need an App Token.

3) To Create an App token I need a User Token.

4) To Create a user token I need to log in to Facebook and have all sorts of permissions on the App. (I can't log in as the System User! FB asks me to login as myself. I am not sure if this breaks the Auth Token generated?)

5) Then there are all sorts of swapping tokens to get a Permanent App token, Another point of potential failure!

6) **IF** the stars and moon align and you stand on your head the permanent App key can be passed to the above call as the **access_token**

I don't understand how to link the Pages I want to post to with the App created. Do I have to have 1 App for Each Page?

I have got one page to work, We initially used that App to Auth against the Instant Article Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/${MyPageID}/instant_articles
```

I could not use the above token for the /feed url, I had to generate a new token with extra publish permissions and the page published with no problems, however when I change the **${MyPageID}** to another page using the same **access_token** I get the 403.

I tried Creating a new App, I have no clue how they link to a specific page So the App to me seems sort of redundant.

Any help with what I am doing wrong or how I can go about simply posting to various FB Pages with a System User using the /feed api ?

The calls are made form a Spring Boot Java APP using HTTP Posts.

Comment: Have you assigned the system user as an admin on the page you're looking  to post to?

Comment: Yes the System user is Page Admin on all the pages it tries to post to.

Comment: Ok. Have you made the following requests: graph.facebook.com/PageIDofPageYouWishToPostTo?fields=access_token&access_token=SYSTEMUSERACCESSTOKEN to retrieve the individual page access tokens? The system user tokens can be retrieved directly from the UI

Comment: @PatrickLambe thanks that was the issue, I was not sure how to get the system user access token (https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users/...) and in turn the page access token. The the Page Access token. I will detail the step I took as an answer.

Comment: ok sounds good, so you have your answer now below? If so I'll upvote. Thanks

Comment: Yes thanks. Finding the system user details you recommended was the missing link :-)

Answer (score 1):

### How to get a System User Auth and Page Auth:

1) Generate a User Token for an App (Button above the System User):

```
https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users/${System User ID}?business_id=${your_business_manager_id}
```

- System user has Page Admin on each page you need to post to.
- App is just an FB app, not sure what it does other that it is a grouping I generate a token against.
- I chose: (manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list)

2) Check your access token:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?access_token=${The access token you got from the step above}&version=v2.12
```

- This will provide you with the App ID the Token is for and how long it lasts (we need a Permanent token)

3) Using Graph API Explorer gets the Accounts this token has access to:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/${Your FB APP ID}/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v2.12
```

4) Using the output above find Page Auth for each page you wan to publish to

5) Post to each page in turn:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/${MyPageID}/feed
```